# Access Postgres database with AWS Lambda function using Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

My 'handler.js' functions connects to the Postgres database and performs few queries using node.js. My function worked successfully in local, but when accessed as AWS lambda, the queries don't work.

I have also added the corresponding vpc security groups and subnet ids in 'serverless.yml'.

The error logs in 'Cloudwatch' just shows the console.log statements before and after queries and the function terminates with timed out error. I could not figure out the issue.

I have attached the example 'handler.js' code below:

```
var { Pool, Client } = require('pg');

export function apiTest(event, context, callback) {
  var connectionString = 'postgresql://username:password@database.server.com:xxxx/dbname';
  var client = new Client({
    connectionString: connectionString,
  })
  client.connect();
  console.log('Connected to PostgreSQL database');

  client.query('SELECT * from table', (err, res) => {
    console.log("inside query");
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(res.rows);
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    const headers = {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    };

    // Return status code 500 on error
    if (err) {
      const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          status: false
        })
      };
      callback(null, response);
      client.end();
      return;
    }

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
    };

    callback(null, response);
    console.log("query success")
    client.end()
    context.succeed(context);
  })
}
```

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could include more information about the actual error. Where does it time out? Does it print out "Connected to PostgreSQL database"?

Comment: Yes. It prints "Connected to PostgreSQL database". I tried adding console.log after the client.query block. Even that got printed but statements within the client.query is not printed.

Comment: If it times out then either your query takes longer than the default 3 seconds or there is an error connecting to the database that hangs the application.  Try to first extend the amount of time that the Lambda is allowed to run to see if you get an additional error.

Comment: @deepakasinathan When posting code, please format it properly so we can read it easily. The easier we can understand your problem, the easier it is for someone to answer your question.

Comment: @stdunbar I tried extending the time but still ended with time out and no new error got displayed. However timed out error stopped after I used "context.succeed(context)". But still the query don't work.

Comment: Is your Postgres database hosted in the VPC? If not you will have to setup a nat gateway. Also, the [connect method takes a callback argument](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#-code-client-connect-callback-err-error-gt-void-gt-void-code-) that has an error parameter e.g. `err => {...}`. Use that callback to verify if you really do have a connection issue. Your current implementation assumes connect() is a blocking call and raising an exception if you cannot connect. The connect callback argument may be the required way to assert that an error did not occur

Comment: @AthensHolloway I did hosted the database in VPC but it seems the lamda was not given permission to the database within AWS. After setting up the giving access it worked. Thanks for your comment